# singer tap-zendesk - how to extract catalog.json with selected:True from discovery mode

Tags: python, json, zendesk, zendesk-api

I am using singer's tap-zendesk library and want to extract data from specific schemas.

I am running the following command in sync mode:

```
tap-zendesk --config config.json --catalog catalog.json.
```

Currently my config.json file has the following parameters:

```
{
    "email": "<email>",
    "api_token": "<token>",
    "subdomain": "<domain>",
    "start_date": "<start_date>"
  }
```

I've managed to extract data by putting **'selected':true** under **schema**, **properties** and **metadata** in the catalog.json file. But I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this? There are around 15 streams I need to go through.

I manage to get the catalog.json file through the discovery mode command:

```
tap-zendesk --config config.json --discover > catalog.json
```

The output looks something like the following, but that means that I have to go and add selected:True under every field.

```
{
  "streams": [
    {
      "stream": "tickets",
      "tap_stream_id": "tickets",
      "schema": {
        **"selected": "true"**,
        "properties": {
          "organization_id": {
            **"selected": "true"**,},
      "metadata": [
        {
          "breadcrumb": [],
          "metadata": {
            **"selected": "true"**
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selected=true needs to be applied only once per stream. This needs to be added to the metadata section under the stream where breadcrumbs = []. This is very poorly documented.

Please see this blog post for some helpful details: https://medium.com/getting-started-guides/extracting-ticket-data-from-zendesk-using-singer-io-tap-zendesk-57a8da8c3477

Comment: When I only add selected=true under breadcums, I get the error "INFO - INFO No zendesk metrics were captured". 

It seems like I still need to add selected=true under schema & properties

Comment: since setting in metadata works for me - the only thing i can think is that it's because of differing versions. i remember that some place in the docs mentioned that selecting true under schema section is expected by legacy taps. here are the versions on my end:

singer-python   5.2.1
tap-zendesk     1.5.3